# javascript - add variable self instead of this to closure

Tags: javascript

I have an object like this:

```
var obj = {
    name: "Tom",
    talk: function(){console.log( "my name is" + this.name )}
}
```

I want to replace **this** with some other value, such as **self**, so that it always refers to my object, no matter where I use it.
how can I bind **self** to my object, in order to get something like this:

```
function(){console.log( "my name is" + self.name )}
```

without writing the `var self = this` at the begging of every method
I'm looking for a function that forces variable **self** to closure of methods of my object. 
Is it possible and how?

Comment: @dbw there are many objects that we need to force the self on each of them

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Please provide an example of code that you want to use. What do you mean by "my object"? Also, your code has a syntax error, missing comma after `name` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea why you want to do this. If you do, then use an IIFE declaring the variable `self`, returning the object after invoking an `init` method on it to initialize `self` to `this`.

```
function create_obj_using_self() {

  return function() {
    var self;

    return {
      init: function() { return self = this; },
      name: "Tom",
      talk: function(){console.log( "my name is" + self.name )}
    }.init();
  }();

}
```

Comment: Doesn't this create a class instead of a single object? Using a class would fix this, but it's not what the OP asked for.

Comment: the reason I need this, is in my ViewControllers I pass an object, like what would you do in backbone.extend() method, but there are some vars that are properties of the object and in callbacks I can't reference to them.

Comment: Please provide more code. I doubt if the above is what you actually want to do.

Comment: @torazaburo Do you have time to continue in private chat?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively,

```
var obj = (function(){

    var obj = {
        name: "Tom",
        talk: function(){console.log( "my name is" + obj.name )}
    };

    return obj;
})();
```

Comment: never thought module pattern would be the answer

Comment: For reference - [Module Pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript)

Answer (score 0):

can you try something like this

```
var obj = {
    name: "Tom",
    talk(){console.log( "my name is " + this.name )}
}

obj.talk( ); //prints Tom
obj.name = "Harry";
obj.talk( ); //prints Harry
```

Comment: This won't work at all. `this` will be the window. Also, you have a typo, a semicolon instead of comma after `self` and no comma after `name`. Why don't you try running this in the console?

Comment: that would mess up the parameters of the methods, isn't there like a closure way of doing this? like running the method in an anonymous function which has the self in it's closure?

Comment: @MohsenShakiba posted the last one in a hurry, try this one.

Comment: @torazaburo this code I have just posted works in the console.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't do what the OP wants, which is to (for some reason) use `self` instead of `this`.

Comment: @torazaburo he said 'I want to replace this with some other value, such as self, so that it always refers to my object'. He didn't specifically said only self has to be used.

Answer (score -1):

window.self = obj. I Think this will work

Comment: yes, but that would only work if I have only one object in window

Comment: Window is global object.It should not violated unnecessarily.